# How to start a new line in tinymce with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to write a few plugin buttons which will generate some plugins in the WordPress TinyMce editor.

Everything works 100% apart from the code is coming out like this:

```
[accordion_wrap] [accordions]This is where some content goes..[/accordions] [accordions]This is where some content goes..[/accordions] [accordions]This is where some content goes..[/accordions] [/accordion_wrap]
```

Instead of looking like this

```
[accordion_wrap]

[accordions]This is where some content goes...[/accordions]
[accordions]This is where some content goes...[/accordions]
[accordions]This is where some content goes...[/accordions]

[/accordion_wrap]
```

The code i have done this is as follows:

```
   if(p == 'Accordions'){

    content =  '[accordion_wrap]'+'\n'+'[accordions]This is where some content goes...[/accordions]'+'\n'+'[accordions]This is where some content goes...[/accordions]'+'\n'+'[accordions]This is where some content goes...[/accordions]'+'\n'+'[/accordion_wrap]';

  tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);

    } // end of shortcode
```

Could someone point me to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: you could insert some <br> s as well